# Правильнее ResponseEntity<?> или ResponseEntity<Object>?

Tags: java, полиморфизм

Коллеги, какой вариант более корректный? При том, что оба рабочие 
`ResponseEntity<?>` 
или
`ResponseEntity<Object>` 
?

```
@GetMapping("/find")
public ResponseEntity<?> find(@RequestParam int id) {
    var object1 = Object1Service.find(id);

    if (object1 == null) {
        var error1 =  new Error1("Object1 not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error1, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(object1 , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```